# Docker connect Mail catcher with WordPress

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, mailcatcher

I want to set a `sendmail_path` in WordPress' container and use a sendmail provided by another container. In my case its MailHog.

So this is my docker-compose:

```
version: '2'
services:
    wordpress:
        image: wordpress
        links:
            - db:mysql
            - mailhog
        ports:
            - 80:80
        domainname: foo.com
        hostname: foo
        volumes:
            - ./public:/var/www/html
        environment:
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: example
        depends_on:
           - mailhog

    mailhog:
        image: mailhog/mailhog
        ports:
            - 1025:1025
            - 8025:8025

    db:
        image: mariadb
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

I tried executing the `command: "echo 'sendmail_path = \"/usr/local/bin/mailhog sendmail\"' > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/mail.ini"` on WordPress container but it actually prints it...

Does these two have to share the volumes?

PS. I know I can use it as a SMTP server in the APP but I want to deal with it in more automated way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have MailHog installed in the WordPress container, so the path `/usr/local/bin/mailhog` doesn't exist.

What you want to do is to send emails via sendmail and those emails must be caught by MailHog. To do this, you must extend the WordPress Dockerfile:

```
FROM wordpress
RUN curl --location --output /usr/local/bin/mhsendmail https://github.com/mailhog/mhsendmail/releases/download/v0.2.0/mhsendmail_linux_amd64 && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/mhsendmail

RUN echo 'sendmail_path="/usr/local/bin/mhsendmail --smtp-addr=mailhog:1025 --from=no-reply@docker.dev"' > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/mailhog.ini
```

Note the `--smtp-addr` parameter must be in the form `<mailhog_hostname>:<mailhog_port>`.

Change your `docker-compose.yml` to build your Dockerfile.

```
version: '2'
services:
    wordpress:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        links:
            - db:mysql
            - mailhog
        ports:
            - 80:80
        domainname: foo.com
        hostname: foo
        volumes:
            - ./public:/var/www/html
        environment:
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: example
        depends_on:
           - mailhog
    
    mailhog:
        image: mailhog/mailhog
        ports:
            - 1025:1025
            - 8025:8025
    
    db:
        image: mariadb
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

In this example, the Dockerfile you have written must be named "Dockerfile" and must be in the current directory (where you run `docker-compose`). You can change the path accordingly. You can remove the `1025:1025` ports entry if you don't need to connect to it from the host.

Now the function `mail()` should work as intended.

Comment: This looks very promising @Dinacel but I'm getting "Could not instantiate mail function" error.

I have the sendmail_path correctly set and it's visible in phpinfo. When I ssh into WP container and try to run mhsendmail it's not showing anything.

Comment: Hi, I've fixed the Dockerfile because there were some errors :  `usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/mailhog.ini` didn't had its starting slash (to ensure an absolute path definition, it was a typo) and `--smtp-addr=mailserver:1025` (it must be mailhog in your example, not mailserver as I've written) didn't had the correct hostname

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work with mailhog host. I tried also localhost but no luck. No errors in the system logs, just PHPMailer saying "Could not instantiate mail function"

Comment: It works here without any other modifications. The wordpress dockerfile is successfully built ? Do you change the wordpress base configuration ? Is there third party plugins installed ? Can you send your phpinfo and the wordpress error log ? It's really strange. I'll check another time.

Comment: Which program is going to read `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/mailhog.ini`?
I've got a [*similar question*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43888542/docker-find-sendmail-in-other-container).